# PHP: Replace Foreign Characters in a String

Tags: php, oop, function

```
$fileSyntax = strtolower(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($fileSyntax, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))); // remove foreign character accents
$fileSyntax = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $fileSyntax); // remove anything that's not alphanumeric, or a space
$fileSyntax = preg_replace("/\s+/", "-", $fileSyntax); // replace space with hyphen     
$fileSyntax = trim($fileSyntax, "-"); // removes prefixing and trailing hyphen
```

The above code will produce the following:

```
Pokémon = pokemon
YO MAN! = yo-man
```

I want to rewrite this for efficiency and convert it into a function soon thereafter.

How can I utilize more than one `preg_replace()` so this will not be a multi-line code?

Comment: What's wrong with 4 lines of code? Dear developers, 1 huge line, as well as 1 huge sql query is not a silver bullet. You write your code for developers so they could read it easily, so prefer readability over... everything else

Comment: Ideally I want to turn this into a function and I want to know how bad my current method of parsing a string is.

Comment: "I want to know how bad my current method" - does it work as expected? If yes - then everything is good.

Comment: @Aaron - Why? We are grown up and live in a society that has multiple languages? What is the harm?

Comment: @EdHeal - I'm writing this so I can generate valid URLs, similar to the format that is used on stackoverflow (`php-replace-foreign-characters-in-a-string`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just so you know, this line:

```
$fileSyntax = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $fileSyntax);
```

should include hyphens, or you're going to stop people being able to type `ice-skate` and it'll become iceskate, for instance.

```
$fileSyntax = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]/", "", $fileSyntax);
```

spaces should really be replaced with underscores (in my opinion) since hyphens can be used in words.

also you could do this for your function:

```
function replace_chars($fileSyntax){
    return strtolower(
        preg_replace(
            array(
                "/&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);/i",
                "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]/i",
                "/\s+/"
            ),
            array(
                "$1", // remove foreign character accents
                "", // remove anything that's not alphanumeric, hyphen or a space
                "_" // replace space with underscore 
            ), htmlentities($fileSyntax, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
        )
    );
}
```

It's all technically one line of code, just spaced so that it's easy to read and understand what is going on. You'd call it by going `replace_chars("TeRríbLé(!) STRinG :)");` which should return `terrible_string`

Answer (score 0):

you can place preg_replaces as the subject parameter, this way what the replace returns will be the subject for anothe replace and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This function could solve a part of your problem I think:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php
It will convert your string into another charset by replacing special chars.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with multiline code or functions, it is much more clear to read and works the same as a long line of code, this is because if something is **serial** it will keep serial and the time it takes to execute will be the same, if you want to speed up the process you may try to make **parallel** threads work on the same blackboard string but that would be rather complex (you'll need to solve all conflict issues).

Answer (score 0):

By simply use my super function:

```
  function text2url($chaine)
    {
    $chaine = htmlentities($chaine, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');
    $chaine = preg_replace('#\&([A-za-z])(?:uml|circ|tilde|acute|grave|cedil|ring)\;#', '\1', $chaine);
    $chaine = preg_replace('#\&([A-za-z]{2})(?:lig)\;#', '\1', $chaine);
    $chaine = preg_replace('#\&[^;]+\;#', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace('(', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace(')', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace('[', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace(']', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace('.', '-', $chaine);
    $chaine = trim($chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace(' ', '_', $chaine);

    return $chaine;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is yet another way to do this that will strip only accents from your string. I wrote this function to use on on my app, whose language is Portuguese--meaning it has all diacritical marks you can imagine. It works like a charm:

```
function stripAccents($string){
    $accents = '/&([A-Za-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml|caron);/';
    $string_encoded = strtolower(htmlentities($string,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8'));
    return $string_encoded = preg_replace($accents,'$1',$string_encoded);
```

}